# Как получить фотографии с яндекс диска?

Tags: php, яндекс-диск

Недавно встала задача, сохранения и вывода изображений с яндекс диска на сайте. С сохранением изображений на диск справился используя [этот класс](https://github.com/DEN007/Yandex.Disk-FULL-API).

Но вот с получением файлов возникают проблемы. Описываю по порядку, что я делал и какой результат получал.

**Метод 1.** Пытался вывести файлы используя метод `get()` того же класса

```
ls($path) - метод вывода всех файлов из указанного url $path  
get($url, $buffer) получение файла  
$value['href'] - ссылка на файл  
$value['getcontenttype'] - тип файла
```

Вот код:

```
  // формирую url к папке с файлами
  $path = '/'.$config['year'].'/'.$palmer_company.'/'.$id;  
  // получаю список файлов из папки  
  $dir = $wdc->ls($path);  
  foreach ($dir as $value) {  
      // если тип файла png, то получаем его  
      if ($value['getcontenttype'] == 'image/png') {  
         $http_status = $wdc->get($value['href'], $buffer);  
         print ' статус сервера ' . $http_status["status"] . '. размер файла ' . strlen($buffer). ' байт.<br>';  
      // кодирую файл, чтобы вставить его в теги img  
         $buffer = base64_encode($buffer);  
         echo "<img class='thumb' src='data:{$value['getcontenttype']};base64,{$buffer}'>";  
      }  
  }
```

Результат: возвращает только первую фотографию.

**Метод 2.** Пытаюсь GET-запросом получить доступ к файлам как описано [тут](http://api.yandex.ru/disk/doc/dg/reference/preview.xml%5B/URL).

```
/**  
 * делаем GET запос к яндекс фоткам.  
 * устанавливаем заголовоки, в ней передаем пароль и логин от яндекса в base64  
 *  */ 

$login = "login"; //можно и без @yandex.ru  
$password = "password";  

$headers = array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($login . ":" . $password)); //формируем заголовки для успешной авторизации

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_URL , 'https://webdav.yandex.ru/3.png?preview&size=250x');
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER , 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Результат:

> bad authorization!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю? Куда копать?

Comment: @Мурад Джелилов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: в $dir тоже только одна строчка ?